# NativeScript Angular 2 recent taken photos

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

The Facebook app shows the recent photos that you've taken.
Because the NativeScript Api's are able to use the Filesystem api and the Camera, I'd guess it is possible to get the recent taken photos in NativeScript also.

[image]

Anyone that can point me to a good blog/documentation that makes me able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pehaprs this plugin will help you out : [nativescript-imagepicker](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker)